# ORACLE, SELECT * FROM 2 TABLES WHERE CRITERIA DOES NOT MATCH

Tags: sql, oracle, not-exists

We have a batch process that runs periodically and validates shipment data, then dumps rows pertaining to errors onto a table called: AN_VALIDATION_ERRORS table.

The first time it runs, i could get data that looks like this(ill do an example with an error at every level):

```
error_seq | asn | po   | carton | upc  | error_code | error_origin | error_level
--------------------------------------------------------------------
  1       | 1   | null | null   | null | SO         | B            | S -- shipment
  2       | 1   | 90   | null   | null | NF         | B            | O -- order
  3       | 1   | 92   | 45     | null | SC         | B            | C -- carton
  4       | 1   | 92   | 45     | 567  | ST         | B            | I -- item
```

When the data is re-validated, the batch process just dumps more rows onto this table, but doesn't clean up old rows. However with one difference, the subsequent times, it dumps ones with error_origin = 'S'. The data would now look like this:

```
error_seq | asn | po   | carton | upc  | error_code | error_origin | error_level
--------------------------------------------------------------------
  1       | 1   | null | null   | null | SO         | B            | S -- shipment
  2       | 1   | 90   | null   | null | NF         | B            | O -- order
  3       | 1   | 92   | 45     | null | SC         | B            | C -- carton
  4       | 1   | 92   | 45     | 567  | ST         | B            | I -- item

  5       | 1   | 92   | 45     | null | SC         | S            | C -- new row
```

What this means, is all the rows that were not re-created, were cleared, and the errors that persist are the ones with an error_origin of 'S'. In my example, error_seq 3 and 5, are the same error, and the rest are cleared, or fixed.

It is easy for me to get a list of the current errors by selecting where error_origin = 'S' in the case that a row has an 'S'. However, i need to also be able to get a list of the errors that were previously fixed. In my example that would be rows of error_seq {1,2,4}.

This is what i have tried, which is wrong, but as an idea of what im trying todo:

```
WITH B_LIST AS (

 SELECT *
 FROM ASN.AN_VALIDATION_ERRORS
 WHERE ERROR_ORIGIN = 'B'   
 AND INTERNAL_ASN = 1

)

, S_LIST AS (

-- ALL OPEN ERRORS
 SELECT *
 FROM ASN.AN_VALIDATION_ERRORS
 WHERE ERROR_ORIGIN = 'S'  
 AND INTERNAL_ASN = 1

)
, CLOSED_LIST AS (

 -- TRY TO GET ALL ROWS WITH ERROR_ORIGIN = 'B' WHERE A CORRESPONDING ROW OF ERROR_ORIGIN = 'S' DOES NOT EXIST
 SELECT *
 FROM B_LIST BL
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM S_LIST SL
  WHERE SL.ORIG_PO_NO = BL.PO_NO
  AND SL.CARTON_NO = BL.CARTON_NO
  AND SL.UPC_NO = BL.UPC_NO
  AND SL.ERROR_CODE = BL.ERROR_CODE
 )
)

SELECT * FROM CLOSED_LIST;
```

This query needs to give me a list off all errors that have been fixed, and using my data as an example, the result needs to be this:

```
error_seq | asn | po   | carton | upc  | error_code | error_origin | error_level
--------------------------------------------------------------------
  1       | 1   | null | null   | null | SO         | B            | S -- shipment
  2       | 1   | 90   | null   | null | NF         | B            | O -- order
  4       | 1   | 92   | 45     | 567  | ST         | B            | I -- item
```

Comment: See the answer from Gordon Linoff. There are additional ways this could be done, with a NOT IN(SELECT ...), even should be possible, though with more confusing code, to join the table to itself (though, as I mentioned getting the logic wrong with this can be a bit easier).
But the general concept is your answer... and, in general, using standard SQL can typically get you what you need without resorting to product specific, or less standard code (and often more easily).

Comment: Not sure how i'd use a not in, since uniqueness of the match is determined by any number of 5 fields.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, if you're matching on multiple criteria, then I agree NOT IN could be clunky (as you may have to do a subselect & NOT IN for each criteria... probably bad performance as well... unless you can do some of the comparing in the subselects... which you may). At the time I wrote that I didn't see your clarification to Gordon Linoff... did his suggestion help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously fixed errors are those where there is no more recent row with an "S".  I am a bit unclear on what the real matching criteria are between the rows, so I am guessing that it is `asn` and `error_code`.

You can get what you want using `not exists`, something like this:

```
select cl.*
from ASN.AN_VALIDATION_ERRORS ve
where error_origin = 'B' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from ASN.AN_VALIDATION_ERRORS ve2
                  where ve2.asn = ve.asn and
                        ve2.error_code = ve.error_code and
                        ve2.id > ve.id and
                        ve2.error_origin = 'S'
                 );
```

EDIT:

For the full list of matching columns (which can also be `NULL`):

```
select cl.*
from ASN.AN_VALIDATION_ERRORS ve
where error_origin = 'B' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from ASN.AN_VALIDATION_ERRORS ve2
                  where ve2.asn = ve.asn and
                        ve2.error_code = ve.error_code and
                        (ve2.po = ve.po or ve2.po is null and ve.po is null) and
                        (ve2.carton = ve.carton or ve2.carton is null and ve.carton is null) and
                        (ve2.upc = ve.upc or ve2.upc is null and ve.upc is null) and
                        ve2.id > ve.id and
                        ve2.error_origin = 'S'
                 );
```

Comment: "Previously fixed errors are those where there is no more recent row with an "S"", exactly!

Comment: Because the rows are at 4 different levels, the matching criteria is the possible combination of asn, po, carton, upc as well as error code. I could have 5 rows with all the same error code, but for different upcs(or items).

Comment: Ok, i think i got this working, doing some testing to make sure before i mark answer. I want to ask a quick question though, is the null logic necessary since if they were both null they would equal each other anyways?

Comment: @SomeRandomDeveloper . . . `NULL = NULL` returns `NULL` which is treated as false.  That is, two `NULL` values are not equal to each other.